# Web <> Java <> Python Authentication / Cross-platform authentication

Tags: java, python, django, authentication, jakarta-ee

We have a webApp backed with a J2EE stack, which handles login and everything else the platform offers. However for a particular piece of functionality (DataScience / AI), we also utilize a Python/Django stack. Ideally we want the webApp to be able to hit Django REST endpoints directly, without placing the J2EE stack in the middle to be redirecting such calls.

The challenge is authentication. Users receive a session id when logging in in the J2EE stack, and we don't want to force them to re-login in the Python stack. We can get session id from browser when it hits Django, and have a service in J2EE to verify that it's a valid session. At this point though we are wondering if there is a standard way to deal with something like this.

Thanks!